# Django General access for user model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a beginner and having trouble with my model interface. I'm trying to create a project about pets as my first project.

Here's the model for the `UserProfile`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True,
                                verbose_name='Upload Images')
profile_text = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Story text')
profile_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name='Foto Titile')
profile_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

So in the profile, the user can upload image and tell story about his pet.
I want to use the page in order to access to all users, and I realized this is in my model. The user clicks on a button and an image is displayed to all users in special page.

How can I do this better? Make a method in UserProfile, create list and append profile_img fill to this list. Or is it better to create a class for these things?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is more for answering questions about issues with their code rather than potential ways of improving their perfectly working code. It sounds a bit like your code works fine, but might benefit from improvement. Is that the case or have I misunderstood? If I've misunderstood, please edit your question to state clearer why this is a problem.

Comment: i asking how can i upgrade my model. I created page for userprofile, user can upload image to this page with profile_img  in model. So i want improve model to user can change profile_img to private only or display on common page. But i dont understand, how i can make this. Create personal class for this or use list in method. Sorry if my question is not related to this forum. I just want some advice. And sorry for my english

Comment: I create one more fill for img `general_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)` and method  `def general_access(self):
  self.profile_img = general_img` it doen't work. how can i record data in my database, using method of my class?